# In click once deployment how does it support client profile?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, url, installation, clickonce

I am making a click once installer. I checked in prerequisites the .NET 3.5 framework to be installed. Please tell me that if i install my installer in a virtual machine which does not have any .NET 3.5 framework installed then how will it proceed? I tried but when i paste the URL in the browser then it shows me the page cannot be displayed error but it is working fine on my actual machine. This is strange. I want to know how it supports client profile?

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with the deployment site not being accessible from the virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to run the bootstrapper (.exe) to get the prerequisites to install, the .application will just fail. (Sounds like you know this)

For me, the prerequisites just install as part of the application. I'm quite the order is like this:

- User clicks install.exe
- Security question "do you really want to install"
- "Installing prerequisites window" shows while installing the prereqs
- Regular "installing app" window is shown
- App launches